# Unable to connect to SQL2005 using VBScript

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, vbscript

I have the following VBScript, which is supposed to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database. But, my connection is failing. Why?

```
Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

dbConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=srv\test1;" & _
               "Initial Catalog=tset_DB;user id ='abc';password='abc'"

'Open the connection
dbConnection.Open dbConnString
```

Comment: And... what happens? Do you get an error? If so - post it - it'll make diagnosis a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotations around your username and password. Try this:

```
Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

dbConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=srv\test1;" & _
               "Initial Catalog=test_DB;user id =abc;password=abc"

'Open the connection
dbConnection.Open dbConnString
```

Also, your `Initial Catalog` was set to `tset_DB`, when I'm guessing it should be `test_DB`.

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005) is a huge help for ensuring that your connection strings are valid.